# Material Date Picker Custom Styling in white style

Tags: android, dialog, styles, materialdatepicker

I want to implement a white theme, mean that toolbar and status bar should be in white also bottom sheet etc.
i implement theme correctly and it works`MaterialDatePicker` dialog i try many solutions here to customize theme for dialog and it never work form[image]
as you can see in the image the buttons for dialog doesn't appear

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Post also the app theme and the style used by the datepicker